# How to limit text in UTF-8 to only script characters?

Tags: text, unicode, utf-8

I want to restrict a UTF-8 string to only script characters in any language. By script characters I mean only those characters in the language's written script, i.e. no symbols or special characters. Same as scripts here: http://www.unicode.org/charts/index.html

Would I have to go off and identify these character ranges for each and every language in UTF-8? Or is *something* e.g. regex, library... that I can make use of?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the language you're implementing this in, you might be able to use [Unicode character categories](https://unicodebook.readthedocs.io/unicode.html#categories) in regular expressions.

The following expression should match all letters and numbers, but exclude punctuation, whitespace, symbols, etc.

```
[\p{L}\p{N}]*
```

Here's a small [demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/maLHCH/1).